# How to use conditional statement in batch actions of Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements, activeadmin

I'm using active admin in my project and I'm modifying the batch actions. I want to apply if-else condtion on it. If the status of transaction is completed then show `Are you sure you want to delete these transactions?` else `Do you want to delete it?` I want to achieve something like this.

This is the demo code that I'm using -

```
  batch_action :destroy, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete these transactions?", if: proc { transaction?(:status, completed) } do |ids|
    Application::Transaction.where(id: ids).destroy_all

   redirect_to transactions_path, :notice => "Successfully destroyed transactions"
  end
```

Is there any way possible to apply if-else condition on it?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the if else based on the number of records we are getting in "ids" variables. It will be like

if(count(ids) is 1) then Do you want to delete it?

else

Are you sure you want to delete these transactions?